# Cannot find java.exe

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to launch a .bat file but I get the error

System cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

I understand that this is probably a path variable, but I have not been able to understand how to fix it, if that is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you fixed your Java path by going into environment variable area? Also, what is your jdk directory location and what can you see in the `bin` folder inside your jdk? Do you have any `java` exe present at all?

Comment: This question belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the path that you provided i.e. `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe` doesn't appear to be correct.  It should point to either JRE or JDK folder that you (probably) have in here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin
```

In there you should at least see the following files (and hence, the addition of this bin directory to your PATH variable in the env vars):

java.exe

javac.exe

javaw.exe

javap.exe

java.h.exe

java-rmi.exe

javadoc.exe

jarsigner.exe

jar.exe

If you don't see the files above, something is definitely wrong! Also, even if you were using JRE (not JDK), you should still have this bin folder present, where java.exe resides.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here's what worked for me:
Go into your path variable and delete: `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\`.
Then add a new one called: `%JAVA_HOME\bin`
This post helped: [java-path-is-not-pointing-to-sdk-path-in-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725405/java-path-is-not-pointing-to-sdk-path-in-windows)

Edit: Sorry, I just noticed that this question was 3 years old.

Answer (score 0):

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@ECHO OFF

:: Export java settings from registry to a temporary file
START /W REGEDIT /E %Temp%\java.reg "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft" 


if not exist "%Temp%\java.reg" (
    START /W REGEDIT /E %Temp%\java.reg "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft"
)



if not exist "%Temp%\java.reg" (
    echo java not installed 
    exit /b 1
)



:: Find java location
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN ('TYPE %Temp%\java.reg ^| FIND "INSTALLDIR"') DO SET "JAVA_HOME=%%B"
SET "JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%"
SET "JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:\\=\%"
::SET JAVA_HOME
set "java=%java_home%\bin\java.exe"
"%java%" -version
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Try this to see if you can automatically can detect the java location.And if it's work  you can put this at the beginning of your script and  use `%java%` in your script (though it will decrease the performance).