# java path is not pointing to sdk path in windows

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

i have set the environment variable

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
```

and added C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin to Path 
in both user variables and system variables.

but its pointing to something else. When i perform

> for %i in (java. exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i

the result is

> C:\Program Data\Oracle\Java\java path\java. exe

How can i fix this?

Comment: the result for path is actually this "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" i.e. without spaces. was not allowing me to post question without spaces

Comment: When Java is installed through the installer, it typically adds `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` to `PATH`. See if it's there and remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PATH environment put your %JAVA_HOME/bin before C:\Program Data\Oracle\Java\java path\