# java.exe not found while running HelloWorld.java

Tags: java, windows, cmd

(I'm a beginner)
I wanted to compile and run a file called `HelloWorld.java`. I installed the latest jdk and compiled the file through cmd. This worked and it created the `HelloWorld.class` file. When I try the command "java HelloWorld" it says that: `"C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe"` cannot be found. When I go into that directory I can see the java.exe file. I have also set a path variable to the `Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin` directory but nothing works.

Why does it keep saying that the file cannot be found?

Both directories mentioned have a `java.exe` file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You list two directories, one ending in "javapath", the other in "bin". Which has the java executable, or do both? Answer by updating your question.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725405/java-path-is-not-pointing-to-sdk-path-in-windows

Comment: Thanks! It worked! After a total of 3 hours. The solution was to delete this path variable: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath and add the one mentioned in the post you linked.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you got it working. Why don't you enter your solution as an answer and accept it? That could help the next person. (It's very unusual to encounter a problem that nobody else has or will have.) It's okay to accept your own answer.

Comment: I can only accept it as an answer in 24 hours.

Comment: Now you're the one teaching me how to use Stack Overflow. Way to go! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:
While installing jdk this path variable is created: `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`
I deleted that and added this one: `%JAVA_HOME\bin`
After that both compiling and executing my file worked as expected.
Also see: [Helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725405/java-path-is-not-pointing-to-sdk-path-in-windows)